# GameObject scope over RPC call

Tags: unity, networking

Debugging my code I faced some unexpected behavior.

I called an RPC using `uLink.NetworkView` on the server passing some parameter including a `GameObject` tagged as `Player`.

Inside that RPC I make a call to `GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag("Player")`

What I refer to by saying "unexpected" is that that function returns all the gameobjects in hierarchy *INCLUDING* the gameobject passed as parameter to the RPC call.

I noticed that inside the editor it appears in hierarchy the gameobject passed to the RPC but without all the components *BUT* the transform.

My question is to know exactly how the scope is working, I seem to understand that the scope of the FindObjectsWithTags seems to include RPC parameters but without the most informations.

Any clue about this?

Comment: This has come up in the review queue as needing a verifiable example. If you're still interested in answers to this question, please consider adding a minimal complete example of the code that reproduces the issue. (Or, if you've discovered the reason for this effect in the time since 2015, it would be great to write up what you've learned as an answer)

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html

Returns a list of active GameObjects tagged tag.  Only Find GameObject at root of scene, No recursive.

Comment: And that's what I was used to know. But when I send via RPC another GameObject it gets added to Hierarchy temporary (for the duration of function execution). That Object includes only its transform and has not any other component. My question (I apologize if it was unclear) was to explain me this behavior. Maybe is there some limitation on parameters type passed via RPC or something else?